# Default Empty in LINQ not functioned so i need to find what is the problem

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

Dears

I have the following code, and it should shows all records included contractors and reportsourcesC, but this code shows only the records which matched with these two tables, but if there are no matching, the records will not show, even that i used DefaultIfEmpty(); therefore , what it could be the problem.

Note:
InjuresConseqs table will join with the following tables
AccidentCategory (required data)
Events (not required data and no problem with this table)
InjuryTypes (required data)
PartOfBodys (required data)
contractors (not required data and there is a problem with this table)
reportsourcesC (not required data and there is a problem with this table)
EmploymentCats (required data)
Shifts (not required data and no problem with this table)

```
public List<ViweInjuresConseq> GetAllInjuresConseq(int ID= 0)
        {
            var data = (from FInjures in db.InjuresConseqs
                        join AccCat in db.AccidentCategory on FInjures.AccidentCategoryID equals AccCat.AccidentCategoryID
                        join Evnts in db.Events on FInjures.EventID equals Evnts.EventID into Eventresult
                        from Evnts in Eventresult.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join InjType in db.InjuryTypes on FInjures.InjuryTypeID equals InjType.InjuryTypeID
                        join Partbody in db.PartOfBodys on FInjures.PartOfBodyID equals Partbody.PartOfBodyID
                        join contr in db.contractors on FInjures.Contractor_ID equals contr.Contractor_ID into contrresult
                        from contr in contrresult.DefaultIfEmpty()

                        join Report3 in db.reportsourcesC on FInjures.Reportsource3_ID equals Report3.Reportsource3_ID into Report3result
                        from Report3 in Report3result.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join report2 in db.reportsourcesB on Report3.Reportsource2_ID equals report2.Reportsource2_ID into Report2result
                        from report2 in Report2result.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join report1 in db.reportsourcesA on report2.Reportsource1_ID equals report1.Reportsource1_ID into Report1result
                        from report1 in Report1result.DefaultIfEmpty()

                        join Empcat in db.EmploymentCats on FInjures.EmploymentCatID equals Empcat.EmploymentCatID
                        join Shfts in db.Shifts on FInjures.ShiftID equals Shfts.ShiftID into Shftsresult
                        from Shfts in Shftsresult.DefaultIfEmpty()

                        select new ViweInjuresConseq
                        {
                            InjureID = FInjures.InjureID,
                            IN_ID = FInjures.IN_ID,
                            AccidentCategoryID = FInjures.AccidentCategoryID,
                            AccidentCategoryLabel = AccCat.AccidentCategoryD,
                            EventID = FInjures.EventID,
                            EventLabel = Evnts.EventD,
                            InjuryTypeID = FInjures.InjuryTypeID,
                            InjuryTypeLabel = InjType.InjuryTypeD,
                            InjuryTypeDes = FInjures.InjuryTypeDes,
                            PartOfBodyID = FInjures.PartOfBodyID,
                            PartOfBodyLabel = Partbody.PartOfBodyD,
                            PartOfBodyDes = FInjures.PartOfBodyDes,
                            authorities = FInjures.authorities,
                            EstmatedLWDC = FInjures.EstmatedLWDC,
                            ActualLWDC = FInjures.ActualLWDC,
                            Contractor_ID = FInjures.Contractor_ID,
                            ContractorLabel = contr == null ? string.Empty : contr.Contractor_Name,
                            Contractors = FInjures.Contractors,
                            Reportsource3_ID = FInjures.Reportsource3_ID,
                            Reportsource3Label = Report3 == null ? string.Empty : report1.Reportsource1 +"-"+ report2.Reportsource2 +"-"+ Report3.Reportsource3,
                            EmploymentCatID = FInjures.EmploymentCatID,
                            EmploymentCatLabel = Empcat.EmploymentCatDes,
                            Postion = FInjures.Postion,
                            ShiftID = FInjures.ShiftID,
                            ShiftLabel = Shfts.ShiftD,
                            DayOnTask = FInjures.DayOnTask,
                            ExInPosition = FInjures.ExInPosition,
                            ExOnTask = FInjures.ExOnTask,
                            EmID = FInjures.EmID,
                            FullName = FInjures.FullName,
                            Phone = FInjures.Phone,
                            Address = FInjures.Address,
                            comment = FInjures.comment
                        }).Where(a => a.IN_ID == ID).OrderBy(a => a.InjureID).ToList();

            return (data);
        }
```

I putted the following code in DbContext to be able to Migrate these two tables; because, I faced a problem during migrations; it could be the problem

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Reportsources.ReportsourceC>().HasMany(p => p.ActionData).WithRequired(a=>a.ReportsourcesC).HasForeignKey(a=>a.Reportsource3_ID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Reportsources.ReportsourceC>().HasMany(p => p.InjuresConseq).WithRequired(a => a.ReportsourceC).HasForeignKey(a => a.Reportsource3_ID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Attached.Contractor>().HasMany(a => a.InjuresConseq).WithRequired(b => b.Contractor).HasForeignKey(a => a.Contractor_ID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Attached.Contractor>().HasMany(a => a.ContractorInvolve).WithRequired(b => b.Contractor).HasForeignKey(a => a.Contractor_ID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
```

Comment: Did you try anything to find out why you got this result? Did you try to join only one table with a DefaultIfEmpty table? What result do you expect if you do that and what is the actual result?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Yes when i lucked these tow lines I get all result that I need // ContractorLabel  & //Reportsource3Label  ; therefore , DefaultIfEmpty() not working only with these two tables

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse in dbcontainer   i have to put the following code to be able to Migrate my tables; because, i faced a problem during migrations; it could be the problem

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<Reportsources.ReportsourceC>().HasMany(p => p.ActionData).WithRequired(a=>a.ReportsourcesC).HasForeignKey(a=>a.Reportsource3_ID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Reportsources.ReportsourceC>().HasMany(p => p.InjuresConseq).WithRequired(a => a.ReportsourceC).HasForeignKey(a => a.Reportsource3_ID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

Comment: When replying to a comment with a larger reply, consider editing your question instead. It has better methods for proper formatting

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was in these two tables ,the following code for Collection inside these two tables was making problems during migration; therefore, i disable them and remigrate my database ,and removed the modebuildir in DbContext, i found that the problem solved, I don't know why and what is was the technical issue because am not expert in LINQ

Contractor.cs

```
public ICollection<Consequences.Injures.InjuresConseq> InjuresConseq { get; set; }
public ICollection<Incidents.Incident> Incident { get; set; }
public ICollection<Incidents.ContractorInvolve> ContractorInvolve { get; set; }
```

ReportsourceC.cs

```
public ICollection<Incidents.Incident> Incident { get; set; }    
public ICollection<Consequences.Injures.InjuresConseq> InjuresConseq { get; set; }   
public ICollection<Attached.ActionData> ActionData { get; set; }
```